# Subdomain serving main domain content on https

Tags: nginx, https, server, http-status-code-301, nginx-config

I got a website with a main domain, and a subdomain. I use nginx. On the main domain I have https and not on the subdomain. However, https://sub.domain.com is serving the content of domain.com, with a browser warning

So far I tried to adjust my conf in nginx with no luck.

This is the nginx conf file for sub.domain.com:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name sub.domain.com;

        root /var/www/sub/;
        index index.php;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/sub_http_access.log combined;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/sub_http_error.log;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

         location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_pass php-handler-http;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 60s;
        }

        location ~* \.(htaccess|htpasswd) {
                deny all;
        }

        # set long EXPIRES header on static assets
        location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf)$ {
                expires 30d;
                access_log off;
        }

}
```

This is the nginx conf for domain.com:

```
upstream php-handler-http {
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

server {
        server_name domain.com;

        root /var/www/html/;
        index index.php;

        # set max upload size
        client_max_body_size 2G;
        fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress_http_access.log combined;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress_http_error.log;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args ;
        }

        location ~* \.(htaccess|htpasswd) {
                deny all;
        }

        location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_pass php-handler-http;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 60s;
        }

        # set long EXPIRES header on static assets
        location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf)$ {
                expires 30d;
                access_log off;
        }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
                if ($host = sub.domain.com) {
                return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
    }


        if ($host = domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name 8.8.8.8;
        return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;


}
```

I am expecting to not have the https://sub.domain.com serve main website content and have a 301 redirect to http://sub.domain.com

Comment: When I add a server block with listen 443 ssl I get an invalid configuration stating no certificate is configured for that subdomain

Comment: no, as I dont want one.